# iOS Simulator lost all keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm on Xcode 9.3, and the simulator has lost all its keyboard shortcuts.
The iPhone/iPad simulator menu does not show any shortcuts.
How do I get it back ?

Comment: try to erase contents and settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it, needs to uncheck

`Hardware` → `Keyboard` → `Send Menu Keyboard Shortcuts to Device`